# Remove some special word from a text file

Tags: c#, regex

i write the following code to remove some word like (is|are|am|could|will|i|we|you) etc from text file but it give wrong result..

```
 Regex replacer = new Regex("\b(?:is|are|am|could|will)\b");
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\output.txt"))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader("C:\\input.txt"))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();
                    replacer.Replace(line, "");
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
            writer.Flush();
        }
```

any one help me......

Comment: What wrong result does it give?

Comment: Specify what you want and what you got. But before that: go to rubular.com and play around with your regex.

Comment: You're not capturing the result of `replacer.Replace(line, "");`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input line is not changed by regex, you should write to file result of replacement:

```
 string line = reader.ReadLine();
 writer.WriteLine(replacer.Replace(line, ""));
```

Also use `@` character to escape slashes in pattern

```
Regex replacer = new Regex(@"\b(is|are|am|could|will)\b");
```